# Regular expression to capture a tag

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following html text and in javascript i need to caputure all the tags "p" that have a class "page-break" and then replace it for any text.

I need use regular expression beacuse this html text is going to be processed like a text 
not like a DOM estrucutre

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
Praesent pellentesque tincidunt adipiscing</p>

<p class="page-break">break</p>

<p>Suspendisse a velit at diam facilisis
egestas sit amet a lectus.</p>

<p class="page-break">other</p>

<p>Donec tristique placerat massa vitae hendrerit. Maecenas nec
massa adipiscing sem venenatis vehicula. Suspendisse mattis pretium
libero quis dignissim. Nulla volutpat imperdiet vehicula. Donec ut
tristique neque.</p>
```

What prevent me to use a dom parser is than i plan to insert a not valid html element i plan transform the previus HTML into this, i need to parse firt like a text to skip html validation and then paste it like this

```
 <div class="pag visible">
 <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Praesent pellentesque tincidunt adipiscing</p>
 </div>
 <div class="pag">   
    <p>Suspendisse a velit at diam facilisis
    egestas sit amet a lectus.</p>
 </div>
 <div class="pag">   
    <p>Donec tristique placerat massa vitae hendrerit. Maecenas nec
    massa adipiscing sem venenatis vehicula. Suspendisse mattis pretium
    libero quis dignissim. Nulla volutpat imperdiet vehicula. Donec ut
    tristique neque.</p>
 </div>
```

as you can see every ".page-break" is replace ir

Comment: Good story. What have you tried..

Comment: why do you want a regex? javascript has a pretty decent dom parser.

Comment: Replace the class or replace the tag "p"

Comment: I need use resultar expression beacuase that text is going to be processed like a text not like DOM estructure

Comment: Trying to find the thread here, but parsing HTML with reg exps is nearly impossible to do correctly. If you can guarantee that the structure will be consistent it is a little easier.

Comment: @eli.rodriguez What's preventing you from using the DOM to get the element, then processing the innerHTML "like a text"?

Comment: @epascarello You mean this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/407071

Comment: I update the description to explain the situacion and the goal better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// your content
var content = '<p>Lorem ips...';
// to match any <p> with correspondent class
var regex = /(<p class.?=.?"page-break">.*<\/p>)+/g;
// to replace it with whatever you need:
content.replace(regex, "<p>MY TEXT HERE</p>");
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xp5Gm/10/)

Answer (score 4):

[Don't use regexp to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/936986). Use DOM instead. If you have plain string, create a `DocumentFragment` and assign it to its `.innerHTML` to get DOM.

Find your `p` tags with [`getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName), check their `.className` and act accordingly.

Comment: I need use resultar expression beacuase that text is going to be processed like a text not like DOM estructure

Comment: @eli.rodriguez you have your string-to-DOM parser in browser in form of innerHTML.

Comment: I update the description to explain the situacion and the goal better

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought of using JQuery?

```
$('p').hasClass('page-break').html('replacement value goes here');
```

this will replace the contents of `<p>` with "replacement value goes here"

or `$('p').hasClass('page-break').remove();` will remove the `<p>` element entirely.

Comment: I need use regular expression beacuase that text is going to be processed like a text not like DOM estructure

Answer (score 0):

It is not advisable to parse HTML with regex. You can use XPath for fetching all the `<p>` with specified criteria and iterate over the returned list and update the `textContent` for each `<p>` as shown in below snippet.

```
var pList = document.evaluate("//p[@class='page-break']", document, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);   
var item = pList.iterateNext();  
while (item) {  
    item.textContent = "New Text";
    item = pList.iterateNext();  
}
```

**Explanation**

`//p[@class='page-break']` will fetch all the `<p>` elements with `class='page-break'`.
`document.evaluate` function will return you object of type `XPathResult`. Using `interateNext()` function you can get its element. 
You can set new text using `textContent` property.

Comment: I update the description to explain the situacion and the goal better